# CSS last-of-type with multiple selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select two elements using last-of-type, but I don't know what the correct syntax is. If this is the html:

```
<div class="Box">
    <book class="small"/>
    <book class="small"/>
    <notes/>
    <notes/>
    <toy class="small"/>
    <toy class="small"/>
</div>
```

I want to select the last book and last toy in the Box, what is the syntax? I though it would be:

```css
div.Box book.small, toy.small:last-of-type { }
```

But this is apparently not correct.

Comment: Just the last book and the last toy or the last book with small class and the last toy with small class?

Comment: Why aren't you also using `:last-of-type` with `book`?

Comment: @j08691 I guess that answers my question. That's what I'm trying to do. o, I assume you're suggesting I need to put "div.Box book.small:last-of-type, toy.small:last-of-type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the property `last-of-type` to both the selectors:

```
div.Box book.small:last-of-type, toy.small:last-of-type
```

Comment: Thank you. This is precisely what I needed. I thought I could just add both selectors then apply last-of-type.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```css
div.Box book.small:last-of-type,
div.Box toy.small:last-of-type {
    /* styles */
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLotzf3d/).

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since January 2021, the now cross-browser supported `:is()` and `:where()` pseudo-selectors allow you to improve this even further by combining the two rules:

```
div.Box :is(book,toy).small:last-of-type {
    /* styles */
}
```